# How do I update parquet file using Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet

I am using spark streaming to make a real-time data pipeline. 
I am getting real-time data from Kafka and processing this data by using Spark.

But when I update existing parquet file on S3 with newly incoming data from S3 then its performance is not good. As I have to fetch the existing partitioned parquet file from S3 and replace the old record with new record coming from Kafka and then overwrite complete partitioned parquet file on S3.

So it's taking much time  because this table is getting updated frequently.

Can you suggest me a better approach to perform update operation in spark streaming?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When we say "parquet file", what we really mean is a directory structure which holds several files in it. The way these files are organized and what they represent depends on partitioning options, among other aspects.

The important thing to understand is that the unit of update of information is a file (from this directory structure depicted above). So, if you have a 10Gb file in this directory structure and you would like to update a single field from a single record, which is only 4 bytes long... I'm sorry... but you will have to overwrite the entire 10Gb file.

Parquet was not designed to work as a database, but like a CSV on steroids, if you permit me this sort of metaphor.

In order to update something stored as parquet, you first need to understand your data, understand your workflow, partition the data in a convenient way and then employ certain techniques.

I've selected an article which explains the problem in far better detail and explains how to circumvent the difficulty. In a nutshell, you will be employing something called Delta Lake, which is basically a parquet directory structure on steroids which provides a number of benefits.

https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/merge-update-upserts/

https://delta.io

Answer (score -1):

Parquet format doesn't allow append, in any case if you want to add something to a parquet file you have to override it completely. In your case you want to update some field and it's the same only worst because it's not a database.

The work around would be to only append information and if a record should be updated, just add a line with the new information and take the latest one during processing.

Comment: " take the latest one during processing"

If I'll take  one by records from existing parquet then it will take too much time.
If I am getting 1000 records then for every record I have to fetch one already exist record from s3 and need to replace with new one.

Comment: I didn't mean to cherry pick your records, but to filter them before processing. You could have an id or something unique to identify a record and only take the latest for each by looking at the persisted timestamp. Or if you really want to use updates you should look at an other storage like HBase, it's not really related to spark streaming but to the storage destination